# Get ANY(col) instead of MIN(col) from a group

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, psql

I have a SQL Query (simplified from real use):

```
SELECT MIN(cola), colb FROM tbl GROUP BY colb;
```

But actually, I don't need the minimum value- any cola value will do- it's only used to show an example value from the group.

At the moment PG has to do the group and then sort each group by cola to find the minimum value in the group, but this is slow because there's a lot of records in each group.

Does Postgres have some kind of FIRST(cola) or ANY(cola) that would just return whatever cola it sees first (like MySQL does when you don't use an aggregate function) or without needing to sort / read cola from every row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using `DISTINCT ON()` with no order by will achieve what you are after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ColB) ColA, ColB
FROM tbl;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63fe9/1)**

The [docs state](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html)

> DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first.

However, with no example data to work on I can't actually compare if this will outperform using `MIN` or any other aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

> At the moment PG has to do the group and then sort each group by cola
>   to find the minimum value in the group, but this is slow because
>   there's a lot of records in each group.

May logically describe what Postgres does, but it does not explain what is actually going on.

Postgres -- as with any database that I'm familiar with -- will keep a "register" for the minimum value.  As new data comes in, it will compare the value in the next row to the minimum.  If the new value is smaller, then it will be copied in.  This, incidentally, is whay `min()`, `max()`, `avg()`, and `count()` are all faster than `count(distinct)`.  For the latter, the list of values within a group must be maintained.

The `distinct on` approach may be faster than the `group by`.  The reason, however, is not because the database engine is sorting all values for a given `colb` to get the minimum.

Comment: That's true. I hadn't thought of that, and that definitely happens when there's no group by clause. Does it keep a register for each GROUP BY colb though? ie. does it maintain a register of MIN(cola) for each possible value of colb?

Comment: I assume it does.  This was old technology when I started working with relational databases . . . oh, I don't want to admit how many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fetch first row at the end of your sql:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-fetch.html

```
SELECT MIN(cola), colb 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY colb
FETCH FIRST ROW only;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Gareth's answer above:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/43e01/2)

```
; WITH C as (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColB) as rn FROM tbl)
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE rn = 1
```

Not sure if it will perform any better\worse than MIN().